# Windows Phone 7 Samples

Tags: windows-phone-7

What Windows Phone 7 demo/reference applications have you seen which really made you interested in developing for the platform?

I know of [Scott Gu's Twitter example](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/03/18/building-a-windows-phone-7-twitter-application-using-silverlight.aspx) and [Foursquare](http://4square.codeplex.com/). Also see [here](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2010/03/30/demo-apps-from-mix10-on-windows-phone-7.aspx) for MIX10 demo apps.

Other than developing games and re-creating functionality already present on other mobile platforms (iPhone, BlackBerry, Android), is there any good reference material and business benefits of developing for Windows Phone 7? Does the Silverlight dev environment really offer an advantage over what is already out there? My gut feeling is that this is definitely the case, but it will take some time for the platform to establish itself, if it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a lot of examples and reference applications here [www.reddit.com/r/wp7dev/](http://www.reddit.com/r/wp7dev/) or search using the hashtag #wp7dev on twitter (full disclosure - some of my examples appear there).
There a examples of what people are openly working on, but one can assume it is a lot more - hopefully this is useful, as it shows what can be done, or is being done on the platform.

Answer (score 2):

As a novice developer, other phone platforms came with a lot of overhead required to build even the simplest application.  The fact that XNA will be available for game development is a huge thing for me, it means I can create simple games for me and my friends without having to spend time learning a new language or setting up awkward SDK's and deployment settings.

More advanced developers may scoff at that, but development tools that are already being used that can work right out of the box for the intended platform is important for the hobbyists.  I think this will open up a huge arena for homemade games and apps just like XNA did for 360 development.

It should also help sales.  I will buy a Windows 7 phone because of this, and I can imagine others will do the same. As it stands, I am going to port my existing XNA games over so I can play them on the go.  It will be cool to show people at the office, airport, etc. projects I have made right on the spot, and even give them the option to play if they have the right hardware.